# Combined ListPlot3D using arrays of different length

Tags: graphics3d, plotting

I have three parts of a ListPlot3D that I would like to combine. The problem is, the middle part has more points in one dimension than the other two, which means I can't combine them easily to plot them together.

So in the end I have `part1` and `part3`, two 10x10 arrays, and `part2`, a 10x19 array. How can I plot them together?

Note that the middle part is not wider/longer than the others, it just has more points to account for a more complicated function graph on that region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

> ... the middle part is not wider/longer than the others, it just has more points...

```
SeedRandom[1]
{part1, part3} = RandomInteger[10, {2, 10, 10}];
part2 = RandomInteger[10, {20, 30}];

i = 1;
{lp1, lp2, lp3} = ListPlot3D[#, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 10}},
     InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}[[i++]], 
     ImageSize -> 300, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2/3}] & /@ {part1, part2, part3};
Row[{lp1, lp2, lp3}]
```

[image]

`Translate` `lp2` and `lp3` and `Show` together:

```
Show[lp1, 
 Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[lp2[[1]], TranslationTransform[{1, 0, 0}]]],
  Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[lp3[[1]], TranslationTransform[{2, 0, 0}]]],
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

You can use `PadRight` to combine the three parts. For example,

```
{part1, part3} = RandomInteger[10, {2, 5, 5}];
part2 = RandomInteger[10, {5, 12}];
MatrixForm[MatrixForm /@ {part1, part2, part3}]
```

[image]

```
combined = Join @@ PadRight[{part1, part2, part3}, Automatic, -1];
MatrixForm[combined]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[combined, PlotRange -> {0, 10}, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ClippingStyle -> Red, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I should have been clearer about this: the second part is not wider/longer than the others, it just has more points because it is a more complicated curve so more points were necessary to plot it accurately.

Comment: @tan_45, thank you for the clarification. Could you please update your question posting  the data you are using?.

Comment: You've managed to answer perfectly even without my data :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tan_45, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.